# Using one annotation as a member of another annotation in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

I am new to Java annotation. I have used the following annotation in my Spring boot application as follows:

Original annotation definition:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
        
  EntityType entityType();

  ActionType actionType();

  Resource resourceType();
}
```

Now I would like to move `actionType()` and `resourceType()` to a different annotation say `MySubAnnotation` and use it in the original above annotation `MyAnnotation` as follows:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
        
  EntityType entityType();

  MySubAnnotation mySubAnnotation();
}
```

But I am facing an issue with using this as follows:

```
  @MyAnnotation(entityType = EntityType.MY_ENTITY,
  mySubAnnotation = <???>)  <---HERE I CANNOT UNDERSTAND WHAT TO SPECIFY
  @MySubAnnotation(actionType=ActionType.UPDATE, 
  resourceType=Resource.MY_RESOURCE)
  public void myMethod() {
    ...
  }
```

As mentioned above, I cannot understand what to specify for sub annotation. Could anyone please help here? Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest that you seriously reconsider this layout. It's highly unusual and will confuse most of your users. However, if you must, examine [`javax.persistence.Table`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Table.html) from JPA.

Comment: Thanks, @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- for your suggestion. Here, actually, I am trying to annotate a few functions, relevant for my use case. Actually, I am implementing state management for my spring boot application. In this regard, I am annotating methods that are responsible for a state change. Basically, the annotations,  help me to find out the other relevant metadata from the method parameters. So, could you please advise if there is any better approach to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn’t include the declaration of your `MySubAnnotation`. Besides that, the syntax for the actual annotation values is not different for nested annotations. You just have to place it after the `=`:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    EntityType entityType();
    MySubAnnotation mySubAnnotation();
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({})
public @interface MySubAnnotation {
    ActionType actionType();
    Resource resourceType();
}
```

```java
@MyAnnotation(
    entityType = EntityType.MY_ENTITY,
    mySubAnnotation = @MySubAnnotation(
        actionType = ActionType.UPDATE,
        resourceType = Resource.MY_RESOURCE
    )
)
public void myMethod() {
}
```

Note that in this example, `MySubAnnotation` has an empty list of targets, i.e. `@Target({})` which permits it only as a value within other annotations. Of course, you could add other permitted targets. That would not affect its use as “sub annotation”, as that’s always allowed.

But there’s not much advantage in designing annotation parts as sub annotation here. All you’ve achieved, is requiring more typing. One imaginable possibility, is to provided a default here, e.g.

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    EntityType entityType();
    MySubAnnotation mySubAnnotation() default
      @MySubAnnotation(actionType=ActionType.UPDATE, resourceType=Resource.MY_RESOURCE);
}
```

The difference to just specifying defaults for `actionType` and `resourceType` is that now, the developer may use the default for `MySubAnnotation`, i.e. both values, or has to specify explicit values for both, they can not override only one of them.